# hibernate - Dynamic sort in a query

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a Dao method that returns list of "posts" and looks like this:

```
public List<PostDTO> getPosts() {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    return postList = session
            .createQuery("select new com.poster.app.dto.PostDTO(p.id, p.date, p.title, p.text, p.imageUrl, p.author, p.category, count(c.post.id)) "
                            + "from Post as p left join Comment as c ON p.id = c.post.id group by p.id",
                    PostDTO.class).getResultList();
}
```

So it basically just creates query and returns the dto's in that case. The thing is, i need to fetch exact same list BUT with different sorting. like i need to sort it dynamically by "newest", "most popular" and by "comments number" and i want to do this in one method instead of creating 3 methods for each ("newest", "most popular" and by "comments number"), how can i do that in hibernate?

Comment: you can use `order by` for sorting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have choice between :

- Use api criteria to build your query and add dynamically your order by clause.
- Add the order by clause at the end of your query depending on your param

ex with 2nd option:

```
 public List<PostDTO> getPostsOrderBy(String orderParam) 
 {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    String query = "select new com.poster.app.dto.PostDTO(p.id, p.date, p.title, p.text, p.imageUrl, p.author, p.category, count(c.post.id)) "
            + "from Post as p left join Comment as c ON p.id = c.post.id group by p.id order by "+ orderParam;


    return postList = session.createQuery(query,PostDTO.class).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: Beware of SQL Injection. I would use setString() to prevent this.

Comment: @danieljohngomez your're right but the order by clause does not accept input parameters, you can only use it in where or having clause, so we need to sanitize the parameter for example with `StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql` from the Apache Commons-Lang library